# Multiple [2] JMX MBeanServer instances exist

Tags: glassfish

May I know what is the common reasons for the following message shown in glassfish 3?

```
WARNING: Multiple [2] JMX MBeanServer instances exist, we will use the server at index [0] : [com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.DynamicInterceptor@43c0ae76].
WARNING: JMX MBeanServer in use: [com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.DynamicInterceptor@43c0ae76] from index [0] 
WARNING: JMX MBeanServer in use: [com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@bbe5d86] from index [1]
```

I have just started 3 projects in netbean 7.2 as below

1. common - currently only one singleton class for property file reading with @startup, @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy. it seems related to DynamicInterceptor in the warning above.
2. web(include project 1 & 3) - simple page with iceface enabled in netbean
3. facade & entity bean (include project 1)  - several entities + 1 generated facade from netbean, it seems use mbeanserver "JmxMBeanServer" in above warning.

I have checked from google, most of them just ignore the warning above, any potential problem for the warning or why the above message is shown? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's a known Glassfish bug (https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-17010). The issue was reported almost two years ago and it is still in status "Open", so I wouldn't hold my breath waiting it to be fixed soon.

On the other hand, it doesn't seem to affect functionality, and as you said, can be safely ignored.